# Switching from 19" monitor to 42" plasma

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi, plasma-tv

I am currently running two 19" monitors (both DVI) and when I want to watch a movie etc on my 42" plasma I unplug one DVI (monitor) output and plug in the DVI/HDMI lead to the TV. (I also have to unplug the 1/4" audio plug from the back of the PC before the PC "discovers" the TV)

I would prefer to have a simple switch/selector so I only have to push a button to select either monitor or TV rather than unplugging things. I imagine the audio "discovery" issue comes into play, but even so there should be a simple solution surely? Any ideas?

System specifications:

- Windows 7
- Intel Core i7 920 2.67GHz
- NVIDIA GeForce GTS 250
- Realtek High Definition Audio

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

http://www.amazon.co.uk/HQ-DVI-and-Audio-Switch/dp/B000IAI57C

Its basically a cut down KVM.

Comment: I reckon thats got two DVI inputs and one DVI output, I need to be able to select monitor or TV separately. (Just like I do when I unplug the monitor and plug in the TV) A simple switch rather than a splitter that hopefully can incorporate the audio so I dont have to unplug that each time either.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called a matrix switch. They come in varieties from 2x2 (2 sources, 2 outputs) up 32x32 or possibly more.

Atlona is one company that makes them, but you can find others by googling for "matrix switch". They tend to be pricey for individual use, depending on what your threshold is ($300-$400 for the 2x2).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any easy way to do what you want to do with your GPU.  You could buy a HDMI to DVI scaler but in my opinion that is money that could be invested in a new GPU.  You need a GPU with S/PDIF connector (make sure your motherboard has one too), and a card that has an S/PDIF connector will also have an HDMI out port.  With that you can always have all three of your displays hooked up.  Only 2 will work at any given time, but that shouldn't be an issue, just enable your 42" when you wanna watch a movie, then disable to get your 19's working again.

Also the little green audio connector is 1/8" not 1/4" :)